# How to add a new column in Pandas by definning my own function that check values in many columns?

Tags: python, pandas

So i have a very big data set, and i need to create a function that checks the value in the same row for multiple columns, obviously the values are different for each column i want to check.

Then if all the given columns to check their values are true, i want to return something and add a new column to the DF to use as flag for later filtering.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need compare by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check if all values are `True`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[1,5,6],
                   'C':[1,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[1,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  1  1  1  1  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

#check same values in columns A,B,C,E
cols = ['B','C','E']
print (df[cols].eq(df.A, axis=0))
       B      C      E
0   True   True   True
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False

print (df[cols].eq(df.A, axis=0).all(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool

df['col'] = df[cols].eq(df.A, axis=0).all(axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F    col
0  1  1  1  1  1  7   True
1  2  5  8  3  3  4  False
2  3  6  9  5  6  3  False
```

EDIT by comment:

You need create `boolean mask` with `&` (`and`), `|` (`or`) or `~` (`not`):

```
print ((df.A == 1) & (df.B > 167) & (df.B <=200))
0    False
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool

df['col'] = (df.A == 1) & (df.B > 167) & (df.B <=200)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F    col
0  1  1  1  1  1  7  False
1  2  5  8  3  3  4  False
2  3  6  9  5  6  3  False
```

Comment: not exactly what i am looking for. I need to define a function because the values are not boolean, they are numeric and i need to check for specific values in some columns and in other for a range of value, and in other if some col has a value check another column for some range, so i need to define very complex functions, i just need to know how to define, describe in pseudocode: if col = 1 then check colB > 167 AND colB <= 200 .... and so on

Answer (score 0):

please try using masks.for example

```
mask=df['a']==4
df=df[mask]
```